# How to resize additional text in the Navigation Drawer template?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How to resize additional text in the Navigation Drawer template ?. It is necessary to change the additional text (in the picture under number 7). I change the size of the main text without any problems, but I cannot figure out the additional one. Rummaged everything, found nothing.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'm trying to change using styles. But the main text is changing, but I need an additional one.

```
 <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <!--Настройка NavigationDrawer-->

        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">50dp</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">50dp</item>
        <!-- item padding left in menu-->
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">30dp</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">30dp</item>
        <!-- item padding right in menu-->
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemPaddingRight">50dp</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">50dp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large">
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/main_white</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: add your menu xml too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
 </style>
```

// xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/whiteColor"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Comment: app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"  This tag changes the main text (in the picture Recent, Trash). I need to change the extra (in the picture number 7)